# Echo current Timestamp from mySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to get the current timestamp from my mysql Server. I know the Command SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. But i need to echo it as a String. Does someone know how I can do this?

```
<?php

include_once("../DatenbankVerbindungen/dbconnect.php");

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;");

echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $query);

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: You can format it as a string in the `select` using `date_format()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias the current timestamp and then access it in your PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS ct;";
$rlt = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rlt);
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $r['ct']);
```

Or, as @Gordon suggested, you do the formatting in MySQL directly and just return a formatted timestamp string:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS ct;";
$rlt = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rlt);
echo $r['ct'];
```